# how to validate integer datatype in oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, validation, types, integer, procedure

I have a parameter with integer data type in a Oracle procedure which produces number of rows mentioned in the parameter into a table.

I want to validate the parameter with its data type. that means, if the parameter value is 5.0 then it creates 5 rows and if the value is 5.2 then it produces error. How do I create this logic?

Comment: If the parameter is defined as an integer, there is nothing to validate in the procedure-- you'll always have an integer in the procedure.  If the caller passed in a different data type, that data would be implicitly converted to an integer or you'd get an error (depending on what is passed in).  Each caller, I suppose, could implement a check before calling the procedure.  But, normally, if you're calling a procedure that takes an integer, the caller would be passing in an integer at which point we'd be back to square 1-- the data type itself cannot have a non-integer value.

Comment: @JustinCave He's right, `INTEGER` does not work as expected.  See my example.

Answer (score 2):

Oddly, PL/SQL does not enforce `INTEGER` parameters.  I would expect Oracle to either implicitly convert the data or throw an error if 5.2 was passed to an `INTEGER` parameter.  Looks like you'll need to add your own validation:

```
create or replace procedure test_procedure(a integer) is
begin
    if a is not null and a <> trunc(a) then
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'Parameter must be an integer');
    end if;
end;
/

--Works
begin
    test_procedure(5.0);
end;
/

--Fails with "ORA-20000: Parameter must be an integer".
begin
    test_procedure(5.2);
end;
/
```

Comment: [The documentation says](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS566): "If the subtype has a numeric base type, then the actual parameter inherits the range of the subtype, but not the precision or scale." It helpfully demonstrates that with an `INTEGER` example. So this is expected behaviour, though not intuitively obvious.