# PL/SQL How do I check variable type

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I need help with my short PL/SQL:
I have a function done with "create of replace" it takes 1 variable and with my exception i want to check if its the right variabletype:

```
create or replace FUNCTION MYFunction(p_variable in BINARY_INTEGER) RETURN DATE PARALLEL_ENABLE IS

not_number EXCEPTION;

BEGIN
  IF p_variable NOT BINARY_INTEGER
  THEN RAISE not_number
END IF;

EXCEPTION
...
END
```

This is just the simplified version of my function. So as you can see I want to check if the given variable has the right type.

Or is there another oracle based exception that already catches this case?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You'll get a compile time error, I believe.

Comment: Well it does compile but not with the exception handling I want to implement.. this is where I need help and this was the actual question, how to handle the exception if an invalid variable was used to call the function from other PLSQLs

Comment: I don't believe you can handle the exception from within the function/procedure you're calling. If you pass the parameter in with a datatype that can't be converted, you don't get as far as running any code inside that function/procedure. Moreover, I'd be concerned as to why your calling code doesn't know what the datatype of the parameter is before they pass it in. That's kinda the whole point of having separate procedures/functions!

Comment: @Boneist thanks for your reply! I guess I have to change the way of handling the exception if someone tries to call the function with a wrong param :-/

Comment: @F.Chrometz - I don't think the function ever sees the wrong type; with an SQL type (say `integer`) you could get a non-integer value and check for that ([as here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28775820/266304)); but `binary_integer` is a [PL/SQL type](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/datatypes.htm#LNPLS319) so as boneist says it'll fail when calling if it can't be implicitly converted, and if it is implicitly converted the function can't see the original value or data type.

Comment: Who or what is going to be calling your procedures? And why won't they already know what the parameter datatypes are?

Comment: PL/SQL type checking is done at compile time. If the argument you try to pass is of the wrong type and can't be converted you'll get a compile-time error.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? PL/SQL is compiled, typed language. Although it is not directly visible it is not scripting, but it supports some implicit data conversions.

Answer (score 1):

How about overloading a function that will receive all possible (anticipated) types and return a string describing the corresponding type?

Something like this:

```
function f_variable_type (p_variable in BINARY_INTEGER) return varchar2
is
(
  return 'BINARY_INTEGER';

);

function f_variable_type(p_variable in varchar2) return varchar2
is
(
  return 'VARCHAR2';
);

function f_variable_type(p_variable in number) return varchar2
is
(
  return 'NUMBER';
);
```

(so on and so forth for all variable types)

and then use the function on your if statement:

```
BEGIN
  IF f_variable_type(p_variable) !='BINARY_INTEGER'
  THEN RAISE not_number
END IF;
```